# Deserialization of JSON response in Execute<T> works only for lists

Tags: c#, json, rest, deserialization, restsharp

I use following code to execute REST request and get deserialized response data of type T:

```
public static T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
  var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

  ...

   return response.Data;
}
```

For JSON content string `[{'key': 'key1', 'name': 'name1'}, {'key': 'key2', 'name': 'name2'}]` this method works properly as following:

```
var list = Execute<List<FileDescription>>()
```

where `FileDescription` is `struct` or `class` with public properties `key` and `name`.

Why couldn't JSON content string `{'key': 'key1', 'name': 'name1'}` be parsed properly?

`Execute<FileDescription>()` returns `FileDescription` with all null properties. No exceptions are thrown.

See also screen shot:

[image: VS Debugging session]

Comment: What are you using to deserialize the JSON?

Comment: I use embedded JsonDeserializer

Comment: Can you edit your question to add in the code that does the deserialization? The second JSON string appears valid, perhaps there's some clue to why it isn't deserializing correctly in that code.

Comment: I have added screenshot

Comment: I'm using Version v4.0.30319

Comment: I'm using the latest version to parse List<T> and got it correctly parsed.

Comment: I'm too: List <T> is OK, but T is wrong!